# Autoloading Traits in PHP

Tags: php, autoload, traits

Is there any way for me to differentiate between traits and classes in my autoload function? Say I have a folder of classes and a folder of traits; it would be nice to be able to do something like...

```
spl_autoload_register(function($resource) {
  if ( /* $resource is class */ ) {
    include 'classes/'.$resource.'.php';
  } 
  if ( /* $resource is trait */ ) {
    include 'traits/'.$resource.'.php';
  }
});
```

Comment: your probably want to change your second `if` to `elseif`

Comment: Doesn't look likely. There is no information besides the symbol name passed to the callback. You should probably raise a bug with PHP

Comment: @shnisaka That makes no sense. Why use `elseif` if the conditions are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Namespacing your traits seems the only easy way; otherwise, just try to include from both locations.

Comment: @Jack I'm not great with namespacing. How would that help me?

Comment: @savinger Not saying you *should* do it, but something like `Traits\MyTrait` would allow you to use a similar directory structure.

Comment: it should not matter that something is a Trait. Just as it should not matter that something is an Interface or a concrete class. Just give the trait a proper name and put it where your other code is.

Comment: @Gordon Surely, you can't be serious. All of your code is just in one giant directory? No folders for libraries, models, views, controllers, extensions, assets...

Comment: @savinger I didnt say put them in one directory but that it should not matter that something is a Trait, an Interface or a concrete Class. Indicating the type is usually uninteresting. And just as your application doesn't need to care, your folder layout doesn't need to care either. There is little point in putting these into a different folder than your regular classes or interfaces. Organize your folders to reflect the problem domain. So when I look at it, I want to immediately recognize: this is a banking application or a blog or a social network. I dont care if it uses traits.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The autoload callback function only receives one piece of information; the symbol name requested. There is no way to see what type of symbol it should be.

What you could do is register multiple functions in the autoload stack, one to handle classes and the other traits, using [`stream_resolve_include_path()`](http://php.net/stream_resolve_include_path) or something similar, eg

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $fileName = stream_resolve_include_path('classes/' . $className . '.php');
    if ($fileName !== false) {
        include $fileName;
    }
});
spl_autoload_register(function($traitName) {
    $fileName = stream_resolve_include_path('traits/' . $traitName . '.php');
    if ($fileName !== false) {
        include $fileName;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, my quick solution was to use `file_exists()`. I've never used `stream_resolve_include_path()` before and the documentation is fairly vague... what does that do exactly? And what advantages come with registering two autoload functions?

Comment: @savinger Well, `include` uses the configured `include_path`. `file_exists()` does not know about this whereas `stream_resolve_include_path()` does. It returns `false` if it cannot resolve the given path against the `include_path` stack

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution in the way you name your traits. Every trait in my application is named trait_(name) and it is placed in the classes folder.

For example my trait_something is placed in the classes/ folder under the filename "trait.trait_something.php".

My autoload function can pick up either the traits or the classes:

```
function autoloader($class) 
{
    $prefix='classes/';
    $ext='.php';
    if(substr($class,0,6) == 'trait_')include $prefix.'trait.' . $class . $ext; 
    else include $prefix.'class.' . $class . $ext;
}
```